# What happens when an upstart limit is breached?

Tags: upstart

For example can I set a limit on VIRT or RES and have upstart restart the server?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory allocation will result in `ENOMEM`. What the application does (if anything) is completely dependent on the application itself.

Comment: I guess falling over would cause upstart to respawn it then :-)